# tcp/ip application layer confusion in receiving data packets

Tags: networking, tcp

> In traditional model, when application layer
>   wants to obtain message data, it needs to go through two buffers and
>   the normal TCP/IP protocol stack. Inside, the software interrupt is
>   responsible to receive the message from the first of the receiving
>   queue, and then copy them to MSGBuff; at the end application layer
>   reads the message data to user application space by system calls.

Please see the figure for an illustration. I'm a newbie in network programming :( As I know, TCP/IP protocol stack also has a application layer. So what is the difference between the application layer mentioned in the quote (Line 1) and the one in TCP/IP protocol stack?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I inferred from your question:
Transport layer buffer differs from Application layer buffers. Transport layer [not UDP] buffer is used for retransmission of lost packet, or for congestion control mechanisms. If a packet is handed in to IP layer by TCP, won't be removed from buffer, unless a proper ACK is received; But Application layer buffer assumes the Transport layer is responsible to reliably transfer data, and when data is handed to TCP by App, data can be removed from application buffer. So we need different buffers.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of computer networks when it comes to application there are 2 very different notions.

First there is the application you are writing (as a network programmer). This could be a web browser (or etc)

Then there is application layer. this could be http, ftp, ssl.

For example when you are using Google Chrome, your application is Chrome and the application layer in use is http

As another example, suppose you want to write a program, lets call it: awesomeAPP. In this program you want to connect to a client using ssl. In this senario awesomeAPP is the application and in application layer you are using ssl

I could only imagine, what the the writer meant in line 1 was application, not the application layer

Comment: "there are 2 very different notions". Well often, the application layer is implemented in the application. Moreover "SSL" is not an application layer protocol.

Comment: Yep, that's true.but what I'm saying is what things are supposed to be according to OSI model